# Iterating through rows with conditional grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example table where rows are ranked, and I'm trying to figure out a way to group rows until the summed 'Size' value of the grouped rows exceeds 16. After that the process continues grouping the remaining rows:

```
ID    Rank    Size    Value
1   |   1   |    8   |   1 
5   |   2   |    8   |   2
3   |   3   |    8   |   5
9   |   4   |    2   |   1
2   |   5   |    4   |   3
4   |   6   |    8   |   4
...
```

To produce something like:

```
Group No.     Sum. Size     Sum. Value
   1             16            3
   2             14            9
  ...
```

I'm not expecting a worked solution, but any advice on how to frame the problem logically/what tools (i.e. in Pandas, Itertools etc.) are available would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through `DataFrameGroupBy` object as dictionary:

```
for k,v in data.groupby('some_column'):
        if v.shape[0] > 16:
                #do something
                pass
```

this code is for if you want to get groups whose size more than 16 and if you want to get rows whose summed values are more than 16:

```
summed = data.groupby('some_column').sum()
over_16 = summed[summed['sum_column'] > 16]
```

Comment: I'm not looking to group rows based on the individual 'Size' value, but rather to progressively going through each row to identify groups of rows that have a summed 'Size' value that doesn't exceed 16. I'd like the grouping to done prioritising 'Rank' so that high ranking rows are combined together, and so on. In the example table 1, rows with ID 1 & 5 have a combined 'Size' value of 16 and would therefore form a group. ID rows 3, 9 and 2 have a combined 'Size' value of 14 and would therefore form another group. This is my intention, which I think is somewhat different from you example.